# Mule Web Service Consumer Community Edition 3.9

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have requirement to consume web service through mule CE 3.9. My payload already built with SOAP structure i.e. Envelope, Header and Body (That's what I am getting as input). When I passed my payload Web Service Consumer internally appends my payload as part of body hence I end up having two Envelop, Header and Body which obviously giving me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error in SOAP response.

My question is how can I avoid Web Service Consumer to add SOAP structure if not any work around other than introducing Java component.

Appreciate you help!

Comment: It sounds like you need to use DataWeave to extract the body of your input payload and pass that to the Web Service Consumer.

Comment: @afelisatti, appreciate your suggestion but community edition doesn't support DW.